# How to remove prefix from st.write

Tags: regex, python-re, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that runs

```
results = subprocess.check_output(["Rscript", "latest_updates.R"])
st.write(results)
```

and returns:

```
b'[[1]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T12:19:34.3653038Z\r\n\r\n[[2]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T12:19:33.1931475Z\r\n\r\n[[3]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-02T17:12:01.3036067Z\r\n\r\n[[4]]\r\n \r\n1 Mar 9 2023 1:45PM\r\n\r\n[[5]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-02T17:08:18.1044511Z\r\n\r\n[[6]]\r\n \r\n1 <NA>\r\n\r\n[[7]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T10:24:21.1608589Z\r\n\r\n'
```

this is a list that contains 7 timestamps from R.

I convert this to a list with:

```
r = results.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n\r\n","").replace("\r\n \r\n1 ","").replace("[[1]]","").replace("[[2]]","|").replace("[[3]]","|").replace("[[4]]","|").replace("[[5]]","|").replace("[[6]]","|").replace("[[7]]","|").split("|")
```

and write each element to streamlit with:

```
st.write(r[0])
st.write(r[1])
st.write(r[2])
st.write(r[3])
st.write(r[4])
st.write(r[5])
st.write(r[6])
```

The data are ok, but on the app itself, each string is prefixed with a `1` , and I would like to remove that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean the output more simply using `re`. Also, you could use for loops to `st.write` what you want:

```py
import re
import streamlit as st

results = subprocess.check_output(["Rscript", "latest_updates.R"])

res = re.sub(r'\r\n ?\r\n', '', results.decode("utf-8"))  # remove "\r\n \r\n" and "\r\n\r\n"
res = re.sub(r'\[\[[0-9]+\]\]1 ', '\n', res)  # remove the [[1]] and the leading 1

res = [r for r in res.split("\n") if r.strip()]  # remove empty matches

for r in res:
    st.write(r)
```

With `results` looking like this:

```
b'[[1]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T12:19:34.3653038Z\r\n\r\n[[2]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T12:19:33.1931475Z\r\n\r\n[[3]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-02T17:12:01.3036067Z\r\n\r\n[[4]]\r\n \r\n1 Mar 9 2023 1:45PM\r\n\r\n[[5]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-02T17:08:18.1044511Z\r\n\r\n[[6]]\r\n \r\n1 <NA>\r\n\r\n[[7]]\r\n \r\n1 2023-03-09T10:24:21.1608589Z\r\n\r\n'
```

it gives:

[image: Result in Streamlit App. Every timestamp is correctly on a line]